# Get an error when decode received PUT data with get_json() in flask application

Tags: ajax, python-2.7, rest, flask

I use flask 0.12 and try to send a PUT request using ajax. However, I get an error **No JSON object could be decoded** when use `.get_json()` method. The content is json and `is_json` returns True. There is my client-side code:

```
$.ajax({
    url: apiTechnicians,
    type: 'PUT',
    data: { "technicianUserId": chosenTechnician.val() },
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (result) {
        console.log(result)
    }
});
```

And there is the server-side code:

```
@api.route("/technicians", methods=['PUT'])
def putTechnicians():
    print request.is_json
    jsonResult = request.get_json()
    return Response(status=200)
```

Any suggestions how should I work with the received data and why `get_json()` can't decode the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't sending JSON, you're saying its json(via content type) but its not.
jQuery.ajax converts an object passed to it to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` data, so to send json data you have to pass json data to jQuery.ajax

```
$.ajax({
    url: apiTechnicians,
    type: 'PUT',
    data: JSON.stringify({ "technicianUserId": chosenTechnician.val() }),
    contentType: "application/json",
    success: function (result) {
        console.log(result)
    }
});
```